# How to make different columns have a different color

Tags: powerbi

I want to make a matrix table, different columns have a different color.
How can I make it?
Thanks,

Comment: Please check this link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FSTiPm5tY8A

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

On the Visualizations pane select Formatting - Visual - Specific column - Series (dropdown your column) - Values - Background color.

[image]

The result could look like this on a Matrix visual:

[image]

Comment: Peter, the answer you have posted is for Table in PowerBI, the question is for Matrix, so I do not think what you have suggested will work for Matrix.

Comment: That's not true. My screenshot is from a Matrix visual, but for the Table it's exactly the same.

Comment: Peter, I tried your method but it is not giving color to alternate columns. All the columns ended up having same color. Please see screen shot at URL https://postimg.cc/6TmHvxFg

Comment: You are wrong again: The question here was about "different columns have a different color". If you have another question then post it and I'll show you how to do it.